# standard debugging way for javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

This is my usual way to debug javascript. Include **alert(0);** to break the flow and find out what is happening.

sometimes when i need multiple check points i do

```
alert('the flow is now in function 1');
alert('the flow is now in function 2');
```

or sometimes just

```
alert('success');
```

i would like to know if there is any standard way for debugging adopted as i am finding my current method very intrusive.

thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to use the console...
eg [within firebug](http://getfirebug.com/logging)

otherwise you can use `debugger;` to break the script and force some debugger, or set breakpoints inside firebug ([demo](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html))

Comment: can i also know if there is a way to monitor variable values in firebug.?

Comment: just hover the variables while debugging and you get their value... but you can also set watches

Comment: Yes, download it and get to know it well. It will become your best friend :)

Answer (score 1):

**Firebug** in Firefox is the best, but IE8 also has a pretty good javascript debugger. You can set breakpoints and step through your code to follow the program flow and view variable information, etc...

Comment: can you suggest a debugger for IE where i can set break points..?

Comment: bundled with IE8: developer tools. otherwise IE developer toolbar: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Comment: IE8 has a built in javascript debugger. Go To Tools->Developer Tools and you can access the debugger through that utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer logging to using a debugger and need something that works in all browsers, I'd recommend my [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating exception handling into your code could also be helpful.

[Exception Handling in JavaScript](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Exception-Handling-in-JavaScript-Introduction-to-Core-Concepts/2/)

And a simple technique for accessing values for simple value checking would be to clear the address bar of the browser

> ("[standard debugging way for javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521528/standard-debugging-way-for-javascript-jquery)")
>   and replacing it with: 
>    javascript:alert(document.getElementById('comments-2521535').innerHTML);

and press enter to run the snippet on the page. It works a lot like the console in Firebug.